# tensorflow and keras not imported in output window when using VSCode . even when it is imported in the terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda, development-environment, ubuntu-18.04

i have installed the VSCode(version 036a6b1d)from ubuntu software.i want to use a conda environment where i have already installed tensorflow and keras libraries. this works fine in terminal of virtual environment. but it shows the following error in output window and also in python interactive terminal.

```
[Running] python -u "/home/rajesh/Desktop/venv/reuters2.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rajesh/Desktop/venv/reuters2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
ImportError: No module named tensorflow

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.025 seconds
```

### setting.json file

i watched several videos including this one
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RTwF9TRrSw

i did as it said.i added the path to extra paths. 
`python.autoComplete.extraPaths":[ "/home/rajesh/anaconda3/envs/venv" ], [python]` in setting.json file conda environment activation.

---

i activated the conda venv environment using Ctrl + shift + P and from there to "python: select interpretor" and from there to venv: conda environment.

in this approach my conda environment gets activated in the terminal and it works fine. but my output window doesn't seem to notice it.

here is my setting.json file

```
{
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vs-minimal",
    "editor.fontSize": 13,
    "window.customMenuBarAltFocus": true,
    "window.menuBarVisibility": "toggle",
    "window.restoreWindows": "all",
    "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
    "window.titleBarStyle": "custom",
    "python.pythonPath": "/home/rajesh/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/bin/python",
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths":[ "/home/rajesh/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/" ],
    "[python]": {

    },
    "editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation",
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.fontFamily": "'Droid Sans Mono', 'monospace', 'monospace', 'Droid Sans Fallback'"
}
```

### here is my few lines of python code. i think this would be enough. the problem is in line 1.

```
import tensorflow
import keras


#importing the datasets from keras
from keras.datasets import reuters
(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = reuters.load_data(num_words=None)

#to decode back to news wires
word_index = reuters.get_word_index()
reverse_word_index = dict([(value, key) for (key, value) in word_index.items()])
decoded_newswire = ' '.join([reverse_word_index.get(i - 3, '?') for i in train_data[0]])
```

---

i want the tensorflow and keras to get imported to the output window from conda environments that i have already created.  so that i could work easily from here(output window).

Comment: FYI if you selected the appropriate conda environment then `python.autoComplete.extraPaths":[ "/home/rajesh/anaconda3/envs/venv" ]`. And the `[python]` part is unnecessary if you're going to leave it empty. And what channel in the Output Window are you seeing the exception? Are you using the Code Runner extension?

Comment: @Brett Cannon thanks for checking on it. i have this issue resolved now. i reinstalled vscode ans set everything from beginning. and everything turned out fine